# rspec unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

When I start unit-test `$ bundle exec rspec spec/` whith RSpec...

```
admin@ADMINPC /d/ruby/rails/projects/CMS (static-pages)
$ bundle exec rspec spec/
d:/ruby/rails/projects/CMS/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:1:in `requi
re': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
        from d:/ruby/rails/projects/CMS/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.r
b:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

How fix this?

File pages_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all:

```
rails g rspec:install
```

It will create the file `spec_helper`.

Than you can prepare the database for test:

```
rake db:test:load
rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: I had a similar issue as described in this question, and I did not realize I needed to perform the install and rake you describe here. Thanks!